# Transformer-XL: Input and labels for Language Modeling

Tags: huggingface-transformers, language-model

I'm trying to finetune the pretrained Transformer-XL model `transfo-xl-wt103` for a language modeling task. Therfore, I use the model class `TransfoXLLMHeadModel`.

To iterate over my dataset I use the `LMOrderedIterator` from the file [tokenization_transfo_xl.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/5e737018e1fcb22c8b76052058279552a8d6c806/src/transformers/tokenization_transfo_xl.py#L467) which yields a tensor with the `data` and its `target` for each batch (and the sequence length).

Let's assume the following data with `batch_size = 1` and `bptt = 8`:

```
data = tensor([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]])
target = tensor([[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]])
mems # from the previous output
```

**My question is:** I currently pass this data into the model like this:

```
output = model(input_ids=data, labels=target, mems=mems)
```

Is this correct?

I am wondering because the documentation says for the `labels` parameter:

> labels (:obj:`torch.LongTensor` of shape :obj:`(batch_size, sequence_length)`, `optional`, defaults to :obj:`None`):
>               Labels for language modeling.
>               Note that the labels **are shifted** inside the model, i.e. you can set `lm_labels = input_ids`

So what is it about the parameter `lm_labels`? I only see `labels` defined in the `forward` method.

And when the labels "are shifted" inside the model, does this mean I have to pass `data` twice (additionally instead of `targets`) because its shifted inside? But how does the model then know the next token to predict?

I also read through [this bug](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3711) and the fix in [this pull request](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/3716) but I don't quite understand how to treat the model now (before vs. after fix)

Thanks in advance for some help!

**Edit**: [Link](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4698) to issue on Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does sound like a typo from another model's convention. You do have to pass data twice, once to `input_ids` and once to `labels` (in your case, `[1, ... , 8]` for both). The model will then attempt to predict `[2, ... , 8]` from `[1, ... , 7]`). I am not sure adding something at the beginning of the target tensor would work as that would probably cause size mismatches later down the line.

Passing twice is the default way to do this in transformers; before the aforementioned PR, `TransfoXL` did not shift labels internally and you had to shift the labels yourself. The PR changed it to be consistent with the library and the documentation, where you have to pass the same data twice.